# Rewrite a path with htaccess taking parameters too

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I would like to rewrite a path of my website using htaccess mod rewrite, taking the parameters too. So, I want that my website executes something like this:

```
mysite.com/chat.php?a=text&b=1&c=2&d=text
```

When I write this path:

```
mysite.com/chat/text/1/2/text
```

How can I do this?

This is my htaccess now, but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^chat/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+)$ chat.php?n=$1&c=$2&s=$3&b=$4 [QSA]
```

Comment: Please do post your htaccess file in your question, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples only.
Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ $1.php?a=$2&b=$3&c=$4&d=$5 [L]
```

---

---

OR to look for URLs specifically starting with `chat` try following. Please make sure either you use above OR following set of Rules one at a time only.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(chat)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ $1.php?a=$2&b=$3&c=$4&d=$5 [NC,L]
```